# Python if...and out of bounds error that doesn't make sense?

Tags: python

I did a DFS solution for fun, but what has been bugging me is that normally if you have an if...and statement, Python will stop checking after the first statement is False. In this case I get an index out of range if I put the two statements together.

For example, this works fine

```
if not nums:
    if s[i]=='I' and (path[i]<path[i+1]) or (s[i]=='D' and path[i]>path[i+1]):
           ret=min(ret, path)
```

But I will get an error for this:

```
if not nums and if s[i]=='I' and (path[i]<path[i+1]) or (s[i]=='D' and path[i]>path[i+1]):
     ret=min(ret, path)
```

Can anyone spot something I don't see?

```
class Solution(object):
    def findPermutation(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: List[int]
        """

        def dfs(ret,nums,i,path):
            if not nums:
                if s[i]=='I' and (path[i]<path[i+1]) or (s[i]=='D' and path[i]>path[i+1]):
                    ret=min(ret, path)
            for j in xrange(len(nums)):
                if len(path)>1:
                    if (s[i]=='I' and path[i]>path[i+1]) or (s[i]=='D' and path[i]<path[i+1]):
                        return ret
                    ret=dfs(ret,nums[:j]+nums[j+1:],i+1,path+[nums[j]])
                else:
                    ret=dfs(ret,nums[:j]+nums[j+1:],i,path+[nums[j]])
            return ret
        return dfs([len(s)+3],range(1,len(s)+2),0,[])
```

Comment: `if not nums and if ` is invalid syntax; you probably mean `if not nums and`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Haxet, does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is just a syntax error using an extra `if`, use:

```
if not nums and
```

instead of

```
if not nums and if
```

Comment: @foslock, thanks for your improvement.